# Reactivity not triggered for root layout in SvelteKit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-store

I am trying to catch a change of url in my layout to show a sidebar component or not depending on wether I am at the "/login" pathname or not. I am using $page.url store to do so.
For a reason I cannot fathom, after using a `goto("/login")` ,despite being able to log the changes successfully, the page itself doesn't update to make the sidebar disappear.
I've tried adding a condition on `$page.url.pathname` directly, going through an intermediate variable that listens the changes from page store and even using a suscribe function directly on the page store. Nothing worked however. Passing a isVisible props to the sidebar component that depends on $page.url.pathname didn't work either.
Maybe there is a valid reason behind that but if anyone could help I would love it.

Here is the code with intermediate variables and my console logs that did print the right values in console.

version of SvelteKit is 1.0.0-next.515

+layout.svelte

```
<script>
   import '../app.css';
   import SideBar from "$lib/sideBar/SideBar.svelte";
   import {Colors, ColorsClasses} from "$lib/theme/Enums.js";
   import ErrorBox from "$lib/boxes/ErrorBox.svelte";
   import SuccessBox from "$lib/boxes/SuccessBox.svelte";
   import Logout from "$lib/Logout.svelte";
   import {page} from "$app/stores";

   let logoutModalVisible = false;
   let isVisible

   $: {
      console.log($page.url.pathname)
      isVisible = $page.url.pathname !== "/login"
      console.log(isVisible)
   }
</script>

<main class="flex {ColorsClasses[Colors.main].bg}">
   {#if isVisible}
      <SideBar bind:logoutModalVisible />
   {/if}
   <div class="px-4 pt-4 w-full min-h-screen relative">
      <Logout bind:logoutModalVisible/>
      <slot />
      <ErrorBox />
      <SuccessBox />
   </div>
</main>
```

When going to /login (using goto) without any server side calls I should expect the sidebar to disappear as its visibility depends on the current pathname. Unfortunately it does not

Comment: Works as expected for me. Though I would recommend using `$page.routeId` instead of the URL when checking for routes.

Comment: Try to create a minimal example. There is a lot of stuff which does not need to be there and probably prevents you from finding the cause of the problem. (You should do this in general when asking questions here.)

Comment: Stackoverflow being helpful as always.. Did you find an answer? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Old question but still no answer. Just try SvelteKit recently and I fell into similar problem.
Your approach is correct as checking the path from `$page.url.pathname`.

But the culprit is from this one:

```
isVisible = $page.url.pathname !== "/login"
```

SvelteKit is somehow inconsistent in the url path with trailingSlash (`/`).
When you first start with the root url, the client start with `/` and after navigating to login page, it'll become `/login/`. Probably, it's different to `/login` as in your visible condition.

A simple way to fix it is using `includes()` or `startsWith()` instead of equal. Try this:

```
isVisible = !$page.url.pathname.startsWith("/login");
```